# Формирование списка объектов в python

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Есть иерархия объектов.

```
import os
import csv

class CarBase:
    def __init__(self, car_type, brand, photo_file_name, carrying):
        self.car_type = car_type
        self.brand = brand
        self.photo_file_name = photo_file_name
        self.carrying = float(carrying)

    def get_photo_file_ext(self):
        return os.path.splitext(self.photo_file_name)[1]


class Car(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, car_type, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, passenger_seats_count):
        super().__init__(car_type, brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        self.passenger_seats_count = int(passenger_seats_count)


class Truck(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, car_type, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, body_whl):
        super().__init__(car_type, brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        self.__body_whl = body_whl
        if self.__body_whl == "":
            self.body_length = self.body_width = self.body_height = float(0)
        else:
            self.body_length, self.body_width, self.body_height = map(float, self.__body_whl.split("x"))

    def get_body_volume(self):
        return self.body_width * self.body_height * self.body_length


class SpecMachine(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, car_type, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, extra = None):
        super().__init__(car_type, brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        self.extra = extra
```

Нужно реализовать функцию, на вход которой подается имя csv-файла. Открыть его, прочитать построчно, сформировать **список объектов** и вернуть его. Сформировать список списков могу:

```
def get_car_list(csv_filename):
car_list = []

with open(csv_filename, encoding='utf-8') as csv_fd:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_fd, delimiter=';')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) < 7:
            continue
        car_list.append(row)
    return car_list
```

Подскажите как реализовать **список объектов** на основании классов указанных выше?
Вот csv-файл: http://dropmefiles.com/3FXx7

Comment: Есть строка, разбить на поля и присвоить их полям объекта.

Comment: У вас в строках файла храняться данные для создания объектов?

Comment: @DmitryErohin да, данные храняться

Comment: Пишете что-то вроде if row[0]=='car':
                c=Car( row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]);
Тут пока ошибка, надо индексы чуть-чуть изменить.

Comment: Ваше предложение понял, спасибо. Вот думаю, а может есть что-то более интересное(красивое) в реализации чем индексы.

Comment: Можете ввести процедуру в класс, которая сама разбирается какой подкласс ей нужен.

Comment: Просто у вас в ините требуются все параметры. Напишите инит с входом row, и пусть сам разбирается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            if row[0]=='car':
                c=Car( row[0], row[1], row[3], row[5], row[2]);
                car_list.append(c)
            elif row[0]=='truck':
                c=Truck( row[0], row[1], row[3], row[5], row[4])
                car_list.append(c)
            elif row[0]=='spec_machine':
                c=SpecMachine( row[0], row[1], row[3], row[5], row[6])
                car_list.append(c)
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь